# Setting up docker compose for development

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a `docker-compose.yml` which will allow me to start up a few services, where some of those services will have their own `Dockerfile`. For example:

```
- my-project
  - docker-compose.yml
  - web
    - Dockerfile
    - src/
  - worker
    - Dockerfile
    - src/
```

I'd like a developer to be able to checkout the project and just run `docker-compose up --build` to get going.

Also, I'm trying mount the source for a service inside the docker container, so that a developer is able to edit the files on the host machine and those changes will be reflected inside the container  immediately (say if it a rails app, it will get recompiled on file change).

I have tried to get just the `web` service going, but I just cannot mount `web` directory inside the container: https://github.com/zoran119/haskell-webservice

And here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"
services:
    web:
        build: web
        image: web
        volumes:
            - ./web:/app
```

Can anyone spot a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that host `./web` folder shadows the internal `/app` folder. Which means anything that is inside is overshadowed by your host folder. So you can follow an approach like below

#### Additional bash script for setups

**./scripts/deploy_app.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

# By default checkout the master branch, if none specified
BRANCH=${BRANCH:-master}

cd /usr/src/app
git clone https://github.com/tarunlalwani/docker-nodejs-sample-app .
git checkout $BRANCH
# Install app dependencies
npm install
```

**./scripts/run_app.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
cd /usr/src/app
exec npm start
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./scripts /scripts

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "bash", "-c" , "/scripts/deploy_app.sh && /scripts/run_app.sh"]
```

Now in your docker-compose you can use below

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
```

Now when you do `docker-compose up` it will run the `/scripts/deploy_app.sh` and deploy the app to `/usr/src/app` inside the container. The host folder `./app` will have the source for developers to edit.

You can enhance the script not to download source code if the folder already has data. The branch of the code can be controlled using the `BRANCH` environment variables. If you want you can even run the script in Dockerfile as well to have images which by default contains the source

See a detailed article I wrote about Static and Dynamic code deployment

http://tarunlalwani.com/post/deploying-code-inside-docker-images-statically-dynamically/

Comment: Very interesting. I think I can see how your solution works, but can you explain a little bit what you mean by "host folder shadows the internal folder"?

Comment: So when you map a folder A from host to folder B in container. Then any content that is there in folder B will no longer be available inside the container. Nothing is copied from B to A, so any existing file inside the container won't be there because you mounted the host folder. So both the folder actually exist inside but only contents of A is accessible inside the container (that is how docker works).

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. What you are saying is that this is a limitation of docker? I believe that my problem is a limitation of `docker-compose` because I can get what I want through `docker` (but not `docker compose`), like this: `docker run -v `pwd`/web:/app -it --rm web /bin/bash`

Comment: Docker compose does everything same way that docker does. It only has limitation that docker has. So if something works in docker it will work in compose

Comment: That's my point, I can see that `docker` can do what I want, and I think `docker-compose` should do it also, but it doesn't with my configuration. I want to know what's wrong with my `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: @zoran119, please check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

So it seems your issue turn out to be be something different

When I try `docker-compose up` i get below error

```
Attaching to hask_web_1
web_1  | Version 1.3.2, Git revision 3f675146590da4f3edf768b89355f798229da2a5 (4395 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.15.0
web_1  | 2017-09-10 09:58:04.741696: [debug] Checking for project config at: /app/stack.yaml
web_1  | @(Stack/Config.hs:863:9)
web_1  | 2017-09-10 09:58:04.741873: [debug] Loading project config file stack.yaml
web_1  | @(Stack/Config.hs:881:13)
web_1  | <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file
hask_web_1 exited with code 1
```

But when i use `docker-compose run web` i get the following output

```
$ docker-compose run web
Version 1.3.2, Git revision 3f675146590da4f3edf768b89355f798229da2a5 (4395 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.15.0
2017-09-10 09:58:37.859351: [debug] Checking for project config at: /app/stack.yaml
@(Stack/Config.hs:863:9)
2017-09-10 09:58:37.859580: [debug] Loading project config file stack.yaml
@(Stack/Config.hs:881:13)
2017-09-10 09:58:37.862281: [debug] Trying to decode /root/.stack/build-plan-cache/x86_64-linux/lts-9.3.cache
```

So that made me realize your issue. `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose run` has one main difference that is the `tty`. Run allocates a tty while up doesn't. So you need to change the compose to

```
version: "2"
services:
    web:
        build: web
        image: web
        volumes:
            - ./web:/app
        tty: true
```